# Changing thumb color of slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider

I am trying to change the thumb color of my slider.

Here is my code:

```
SliderTheme(
                    data: SliderThemeData(
                      thumbColor: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                    child: Slider(
                      value: height.toDouble(),
                      min: 120,
                      max: 220,
                      onChanged: (double newValue){
                        setState(() {
                          height = newValue.toInt();
                        });
                      },
                      inactiveColor: Color(0xff8d8e98),
                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
```

Here is the output:
[image: slider]

However if I remove `activeColor: Colors.white` property from above code then I am getting the desired thumb color.

However if I add `activeColor` parameter back then even thumb color changes.

How to get thumb color as pink and active color as white?

Here is my required output:

[image: slider]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `activeTrackColor:` rather than `activeColor:`, e.g:

```
data: SliderThemeData(
  thumbColor: Colors.pink,
  activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
  inactiveColor: Color(0xff8d8e98),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overlayColor` for shade around thumb and `activeTrackColor` properties of SliderThemeData.

```
SliderTheme(
      data: SliderThemeData(
        thumbColor: Colors.pink,
        overlayColor:Colors.pink[50],
        activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Slider(
        value: sliderValue.toDouble(),
        max: 100.0,
        min: 0.0,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
        onChanged: (double newValue) {
          setState(() {
            sliderValue = newValue;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
```